# How much intellisense should I expect for jquery in VS2008?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I read ScottGu's blog entry (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) a while back, and it seems to imply more functionality than I'm seeing.  I have VS2008 and its service pack installed, and I am using a new MVC project with the RC1 version of asp.net MVC.  I referenced the jquery-1.2.6.js script, and I can see intellisense when I type "$." but anything after that shows nothing.  This isn't particularly helpful for a jquery novice like me, so I'm hopeful that I've just forgotten something.

For example, when I try to use the specific script example in Scott's blog post:
[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/jquerynov/step7.png))</sub>

I don't get any intellisense action for the "attr" that he shows the tooltip for.  Should I expect this intellisense help, and if so, what can I look for to address the problem?

Here's my script reference.  It's declared in a master page, FWIW, and my attempted use of jquery is in my page that references this master page.

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="~/Content/styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you installed the jQuery-vsdoc.js file as well (in the same location as jquery-1.2.6.js)? This file contains the comments for intellisense. It's documented in step 3 of ScottGu's blog post.

Update:

And you also installed the [Visual Studio patch](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736)?

For me it works (as shown in ScottGu's blog), although I'm using a website project, not MVC. I added the script reference in the master page:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I get intellisense in both the master page and in content pages (tried it with the code you put in your question).

Comment: Yeah, that file is there.  It seems to be included by default in a new MVC project.  I figured I wouldn't see any intellisense at all if that file wasn't in the correct place.

Comment: Tried it, and (after installing the VS patch) it works as expected (see updated answer).

Comment: It seems like that might have done it.  I guess I incorrectly assumed that VS2008 SP1 was all I needed.  Thanks!